# Automating PostgreSQL output to csv

Tags: postgresql

```
mohpc04pp1: /h/u544835 % psql arco
Welcome to psql 8.1.17, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
   \h for help with SQL commands
   \? for help with psql commands
   \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
   \q to quit

WARNING:  You are connected to a server with major version 8.3,
but your psql client is major version 8.2.  Some backslash commands,
such as \d, might not work properly.

dbname=> \o /h/u544835/data25000.csv
dbname=> select url from urltable where scoreid=1 limit 25000;
dbname=> \q
```

This is took from a link online of basically what I have been doing, but what I need to do is make a script that I can use to produce csv files daily

So my aim of the script is to while in the script connect to the db, run the \o etc commands then close it

but I'm having trouble scripting it to say go into the psql arco database then run those queries.

command line to connect to db = **psql arco** then once the scrits recognised I'm in that databse perform those commands to automate a query to a csv file.

if anyone can get me started or point me towards reading material for me to get past that bit, it will be duely appreciated.

i'm running all this off a standard windows xp, ssh'ing to a SLES set-up web server that holds my postgresql database running psql version 8.1.17

Comment: Examine closely the [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) documentation.

Comment: So, psql is version 8.1. But what is the version of PostgreSQL? Your output from psql seems to indicate 8.3? What does `SELECT version()` give you?

Comment: version                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.1.17 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Erwin's help and a link I read up on he posted for me I managed to combine the two to get

```
#!/bin/sh

dbname='arco'
username=''   # If you actually supply a username, you need to add the -U switch!
psql $dbname $username << EOF
\f ,
\o /h/u544835/showme.csv
SELECT * FROM storage;
EOF
```

which will write my queries to a csv file etc for me.

From what there is above, it is not separating the sql query so if I load it straight into excel, they all stay in the same column too which means I'm having a problem with the delimiter

I've tried tabbed delimiters, also tried , ; etc but none are letting me separate it
I need for it 
is there an option I can click to see which delimiter is being used with my psql? or a different way of dumping the data from a query into a file that can be read by excel, so a different column for each row etc

Comment: I took the liberty to edit in the answer to your last question and a few other details. BTW, you should be able to define any field separator when opening the file in Excel. At least, OOo Calc can do that.

Comment: just trying to set it up in the script so I can just double click, it's setting the delimiter like you said but it's not seperating the columns from the sql query, tried the | delimeter as it's showing too but no luck:
     b_group     | used_space | disk_quota | grace_period 
-----------------+------------+------------+--------------
 EandT-Mech      |    35749.5 |    37434.2 | none

is how it's displayed, probably won't go out right in the text box but I assume you know what I mean

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this: `it's not seperating the columns from the sql query`. Edit complex stuff into your question, not into comments, please. Add a short comment to get my attention if needed.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should fix your setup. As it turns out, we are dealing with PostgreSQL 8.1 here. This version has [reached end of live in 2010](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You need to seriously think about **upgrading** - or at least remind the guys running the server. Current version is 9.1.

The command you are looking for:

```
psql arco -c "\copy (select url from urltable where scoreid=1 limit 25000) to '/h/u544835/data25000.csv'"
```

Assuming your db is named "arco". Adjusted for changed question (including changed port).

I now see version 8.1 popping up in your question, but it's all contradictory. You need Postgres **8.2 or later** to use a query (instead of a table) with the `\copy` meta-command.

[Details about `psql` in the fine manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html)

---

#### Alternative approach that should work with obsolete PostgreSQL 8.1:

```
psql arco -o /h/u544835/data25000.csv -t -A -c 'SELECT url FROM urltable WHERE scoreid = 1 LIMIT 25000'
```

Find some more info about these command line options under this [related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14770/3684).

---

#### With function (syntax compatible with 8.1)

Another way would be to create a server side function (if you can!) that executes COPY from a temp table (old syntax - works with pg 8.1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_copy_file()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

CREATE TEMP TABLE u_tmp AS (
    SELECT url FROM urltable WHERE scoreid = 1 LIMIT 25000
    );

COPY u_tmp TO '/h/u544835/data25000.csv';

DROP TABLE u_tmp;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then from the shell:

```
psql arco -c 'SELECT f_copy_file()'
```

---

#### Change the separator

`\f` sets the field separator. I quote the manual again:

> -F separator
> --field-separator=separator
>
> Use separator as the field separator for unaligned output.
> This is equivalent to \pset fieldsep or \f.

Or you can change the column separator in Excel, here are the [instructions from MS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx#BMchange_the_separator_in_all_.csv_text).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working for me, I've editted my original post's with my exact data/ versions etc now, so when I make a script
vi test
then input my version of what you put it doesn't seem to be wanting to connect then it doesnt like the -c "\ copy ( select      section.

Comment: @Zenaphor: I actually tested it (with Postgres 9.1) before posting and it works for me. I adjusted my answer to your changed question and added some more information.

Comment: due to restrictions at work I'm not in a position to upgrde the postgres sql, is there another away around me trying to get the outcome I need?

Comment: @Zenaphor: Yes, there are other ways. Please add to your question: OS of your local system? Is the server running locally? Version of PostgreSQL - from the output of `SELECT version()`?

Comment: @Zenaphor: I added alternative answers.

Comment: Morning Erwin when I run your alternative approach that should work, I'm presented with psql: FATAL:  role " " does not exist
./t: line 3: and then doesnt recognise the tac command but it writes the csv file but nothing in it?

Comment: @Zenaphor: Good day! `-tAc` is just `-t -A -c` Maybe your system does not allow collapsing options. Follow the link to the manual I provided. Also, if you need to provide a User ad `-U <dbuser>`.

Comment: 'Erwin, dont suppose you could help me once more. with what I have posted below, how would I go about ensuring adding a ',' to seperate my columns in the csv file, so if I opened the csv file up with excel for example, they are in seperate boxes?